# Cluster details in the SF Explorer: Load Metric Information

Tags: azure-service-fabric

On the Details page of the cluster, in the section `Load Metric Information`, I can see constantly changing values for `Action` column.
It is changing from `Creation` to `CreationWithMove` and back again for `Count`, `PrimaryCount` and `ReplicaCount`. For other entries it shows `NoActionNeeded`.

What does that mean? And can it cause timeouts on client-side connecting to the cluster?
My cluster manifest:

```
<NodeTypes>
  <NodeType Name="NodeType0">
    <Endpoints>
      <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19000" />
      <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19002" />
      <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19001" />
      <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19080" Protocol="http" />
      <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19003" />
      <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="20001" EndPort="20031" />
      <EphemeralEndpoints StartPort="20032" EndPort="20287" />
    </Endpoints>
    <PlacementProperties>
      <Property Name="NodeTypeName" Value="NodeType0" />
    </PlacementProperties>
  </NodeType>
</NodeTypes>
<Infrastructure>
  <WindowsServer>
    <NodeList>
      <Node NodeName="vm0" IPAddressOrFQDN="test.env.com" NodeTypeRef="NodeType0" FaultDomain="fd:/dc1/r0" UpgradeDomain="UD0" />
      <Node NodeName="vm1" IPAddressOrFQDN="test.env.com" NodeTypeRef="NodeType0" FaultDomain="fd:/dc2/r0" UpgradeDomain="UD1" />
      <Node NodeName="vm2" IPAddressOrFQDN="test.env.com" IsSeedNode="true" NodeTypeRef="NodeType0" FaultDomain="fd:/dc3/r0" UpgradeDomain="UD2" />
      <Node NodeName="vm3" IPAddressOrFQDN="test.env.com" IsSeedNode="true" NodeTypeRef="NodeType0" FaultDomain="fd:/dc4/r0" UpgradeDomain="UD3" />
      <Node NodeName="vm4" IPAddressOrFQDN="test.env.com" IsSeedNode="true" NodeTypeRef="NodeType0" FaultDomain="fd:/dc5/r0" UpgradeDomain="UD4" />
    </NodeList>
  </WindowsServer>
</Infrastructure>
<FabricSettings>
  <Section Name="ClusterManager">
    <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    <Parameter Name="PlacementConstraints" Value="NodeTypeName==NodeType0" />
    <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
  </Section>
  <Section Name="FailoverManager">
    <Parameter Name="ExpectedClusterSize" Value="5" />
    <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    <Parameter Name="PlacementConstraints" Value="NodeTypeName==NodeType0" />
    <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
  </Section>
  <Section Name="FaultAnalysisService">
    <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    <Parameter Name="PlacementConstraints" Value="NodeTypeName==NodeType0" />
    <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
  </Section>
  <Section Name="Federation">
    <Parameter Name="NodeIdGeneratorVersion" Value="V4" />
  </Section>
  <Section Name="Hosting">
    <Parameter Name="EndpointProviderEnabled" Value="true" />
    <Parameter Name="FirewallPolicyEnabled" Value="true" />
    <Parameter Name="RunAsPolicyEnabled" Value="true" />
  </Section>
  <Section Name="HttpGateway">
    <Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
  </Section>
  <Section Name="NamingService">
    <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    <Parameter Name="PlacementConstraints" Value="NodeTypeName==NodeType0" />
    <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
  </Section>
  <Section Name="ReconfigurationAgent">
    <Parameter Name="IsDeactivationInfoEnabled" Value="true" />
  </Section>
  <Section Name="Security">
    <Parameter Name="ClientRoleEnabled" Value="true" />
    <Parameter Name="ClusterCredentialType" Value="None" />
    <Parameter Name="DisableFirewallRuleForDomainProfile" Value="true" />
    <Parameter Name="DisableFirewallRuleForPrivateProfile" Value="true" />
    <Parameter Name="DisableFirewallRuleForPublicProfile" Value="true" />
    <Parameter Name="ServerAuthCredentialType" Value="None" />
  </Section>
  <Section Name="UpgradeOrchestrationService">
    <Parameter Name="AutoupgradeEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Parameter Name="ClusterId" Value="568fbf20-048e-43dc-828e-dd42df9c662f" />
    <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    <Parameter Name="PlacementConstraints" Value="NodeTypeName==NodeType0" />
    <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
  </Section>
</FabricSettings>
```

Comment: I think it may be worthwhile to include an example JSON configuration for your setup. It sounds like one of your nodes might be crashing periodically and getting recreated. Some articles online indicate that Diagnostic Events Viewer might help you find the cause (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-diagnostics-how-to-monitor-and-diagnose-services-locally/). Some other ideas off the top of my head...are you using a load balancer that temporarily invalidates some of your nodes' bound addresses? Are you using less nodes than you should be?

Comment: @Alexandru 1) nodes are not crashing, I'm 90% sure; 2) no load balancer — on premises cluster; 3) I'm using 5-nodes cluster so it should be sufficient, but can see obstacles with finding a place for replicas only after upgrade and not after a first deploy. Will add my config just a little bit later.

Comment: @Alexandru added the manifest.

Comment: What happens if you set `MinReplicaSetSize` and `TargetReplicaSetSize` to 1 on the `FailoverManager` section?

Comment: @Alexandru don't know. I've moved from on-premises cluster to Azure and there are no such issues. I'm not able to use on-premises cluster again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the same behavior, and after a little trial and error, I found out that it happens with stateless applications (I’ve tested only 2 so far) that has instance count of -1.

When I set the instance count to any number in range 1..<number_of_nodes>
the *Action* value of *Count*, *PrimaryCount* and *ReplicaCount* metrics under *Load Metric Information* table in the Cluster *DETAILS* tab no longer changes every second to **Creation** and **CreationWithMove**, instead it stays **NoActionNeeded**.